# How to return a partial view and invoke the model's constructor with DI system

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a parent view, and want to call a handler with ajax that will return a partial view. The problem I'm having is that my partial view needs it's model also which has all its own OnGet, OnPost etc methods.

When calling:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetPartialView(Guid Id)
    {
        return Partial("MyPartialView");
    }
```

I don't know how to add the model for this view, as its only constructor takes several services that usually the DI systems takes care of for me. I also need to pass the Id to the partial view as its used in the OnGet method (which I'm assuming will be invoked when this works properly).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the model to the partial view in razor pages, you need to add the second parameter as the model you need to pass when returning to the Partial：

```
return Partial("MyPartialView", model);
```

It should be noted that in `MyPartialView`, you need to **delete the @Page** in the first line of the page and `add the model reference you passed`.

This will ensure that MyPartialView receives the model data, otherwise there will be an error that model is null.

Regarding the `OnGet and OnPost` methods of the `MyPartialView` page you mentioned, if you delete `@Page`, they will lose their actual contact meaning.

My suggestion is that if you have some post or get methods that need to be used in MyPartialView, you can write these methods to other pages.

Here is a complete example:

TestModel.cshtml.cs:

```
  public class TestModel : PageModel
    { 
        public void OnGet()
        {  
        }
        public PartialViewResult OnGetPartialView(Guid Id)
        {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>()
            {
                 new Person(){ Age = 12,
                FirstName = "dd",
                LastName = "aa" },
                   new Person(){ Age = 13,
                FirstName = "bb",
                LastName = "ff" },
                     new Person(){ Age = 14,
                FirstName = "ggr",
                LastName = "rwe" },

            }; 
            return Partial("MyPartialView", persons);
        } 

        public IActionResult OnPostTest()
        {
            return Content("aa");
        }
    }
```

TestModel.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_razorpage_new.Pages.TestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Test</h1>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get partial view" /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="partial" class="border"></div>  

@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () { 
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "/Test?handler=PartialView", 
                    data: { Id: "780cd7ce-91b2-40fd-b4c8-7efa6b7c84a5" },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#partial").html(data);
                    } 
                });

            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

MyPartialView.cshtml:

```
@model List<Person> 
<form method="post">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Click()" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Age</td>
                <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                <td>@item.LastName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

</form>

<script>
    function Click() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Test?handler=test",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Text1").val(data);
            } 
        });
    }

</script>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Great answer thank you. If I give my model for the partial view a more complex class that has OnPost method, is it possible to call this when a form is submitted from the partial veiw?

Comment: @Josh, If the OnPost method you mentioned is in the code behind of the partial veiw, when you submit the form in the partial veiw, you cannot trigger it, because according to my previous suggestion, the `@Page` of the partial veiw has been deleted, so If you call it's post method, a 404 error will occur.
I suggest that you can transfer the onpost method to other page backends like the case in my answer.
If you have any questions, you can directly provide us with the code for reference.

Comment: Thats answered everything. Thanks again for the detailed answer!